# Exporting table to text field but getting hhmmss in the Date/Time field

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im trying to export a table to a text file using the following process:

Right Click on Table | Export | Text File

This all works fine but one of my fields is a Data/Time field and exports the values in it like so:

```
0:00:00
```

I did a bit of research on this and found this by Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291245 which explains why this happens and provides a couple of solutions.

Not of these solutions actually work for me because I need a , as a delimiter and don't want the 0:00:00 to appear. Sow whats the best way of doing this?

Thanks

I'm open to suggestions either via VBA or through a MS wizard

Comment: Why does the query method mentioned in the solutions not work for you?

Comment: well the second one i tried and it got rid of the hhmmss but i need the delimiter - the first I don't know what the steps are to make it - like is that done in a wizard or is it done via SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your table to the query design window. Add all the fields you need to the design grid. Change the date field to:

```
MyDate: Format(TheDateField,"yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Or any other combination of year, month, day that works for you. Save the query. Choose to export the query. You can do this with Right-Click, with the External data tab, or via VBA:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "MyQuery", "z:\docs\myquery.csv"
```

[image: add table]

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214141(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: that sorted it but how do i go about referencing an already created export format called "Report"? Do I place it after the acExportDelim?

Comment: Yes, but I think you should recreate your export specification, because the old one will not match. MyDate in the example is text, not date.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? are you saying it should be called something else?

Comment: is there also a way to include in the export format all the field names on the first row?

Comment: I included a link to the TransferText method. The fifth argument is HasFieldNames, use True to include field names.

Comment: "what do you mean exactly? are you saying it should be called something else?" I mean that you should rebuild the specification. The name is not important.

Comment: great answer - sorry for not reading every bit there remou - my impatience wanted an answer fast - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

An other solution could be to first, create a table based on query with correct date format, and then export this table.

By this way, you can still have a date and not a string on your exported file, so it can be sort!

Microsoft brings us some more details for this resolution  right here :
[When you export date fields to text, the time format is included Abstract](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291245)